# Making Onchange Work on Page Load

Tags: javascript, onchange, onload

I have a select tag as listed below which has a coded onchange event.

```
<select style="font-size: 90%;" name="Color" id="selection" 
onchange="document.getElementById('title1').innerHTML = TitleName1[this.value];"> 
<option value="2">SELECT ROUND</option>
<option value="1">ROUND 1</option>
<option value="2">ROUND 2</option>
</select></div>

<script>
var TitleName1 = {
"1" : "CARL",
"2" : "RICH",
};
</script>

<div id="title1" >SATURDAY</div>
```

When my page loads, the HTML div shows "SATURDAY", I want to change this so that on page load it shows in this case "RICH" which aligns with value 2. I've tried the following and a few other combinations but no luck.

```
<select style="font-size: 90%;" name="Color" id="selection" 
onchange="document.getElementById('title1').innerHTML = TitleName1[this.value];" 
onload="document.getElementById('title1').innerHTML = TitleName1[this.value];">
```

Comment: `<script>document.getElementById('title1').innerHTML = TitleName1[document.getElementById('selection').value];</script>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code inside .

```
window.onload = function(){
   document.getElementById('title1').innerHTML = 
   TitleName1[document.getElementById('selection').value]
}
```

Live Example [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8txgy4cn/)

Comment: This is perfect, thank you very much for the quick response. Very much appreciated.